# Unable to define sub variable with Object key name

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create an object/array key, then defining a sub object for that new key.

```
var myObject = {};
var newKey = function(key, value, otherval) {
    myObject[key] = value;
    myObject[key].subval = otherval;
};

newKey('google', 'wiki', 'yahoo');
```

it creates `myObject.google` fine and gives it a value of 'wiki', but it doesn't create `myObject.google.subval` at all. How do I do this with ONE function?

Comment: You can do `myObject[key].subval` only if `myObject[key]` is an object, but in your case, it is a string (`wiki`).

Comment: that makes an unfortunate amount of sense :P

Comment: Yup... So, may want to think about structuring the data differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myObject.google is already equal to "wiki", which is a string.

You could do something like ([jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/cb5HL/2/)):

```
var myObject = {};
var newKey = function(key, value, otherval) {
    myObject[key] = {'value':value, 'subval':otherval}
};

newKey('google', 'wiki', 'yahoo');

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myObject.key` can't be a string if you want to assign a subval to it. It has to be an object. So you would write:

```
var myObject = {};
var newKey = function(key, value, subval, otherval) {
    myObject[key] = {'value' : value};
    myObject[key][subval] = {'value': otherval}; //or myObject[key][subval] = otherval; if your subval wouldn't be having any sub-subvals later on
};

newKey('googleKey', 'google', 'yahooKey', 'yahoo');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all The **Requirement** you asked is **Wrong Structure**, here is what you have asked.

**You structure would be Transformed like this from the posted function**

```
    var myObject = {

                   google: 'wiki'

                   };
```

**console.log(myObject.google)** OUTPUTS **wiki**

What you are asking :

```
var myObject = {

               google : {

                         subval : 'yahoo'
                        }

    };
```

Now **console.log(myObject.google.subval)** OUTPUTS **yahoo**

Working [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsbin.com/OGAcIwE/1/watch?js,console)

**Why your Q / Structure is WRONG ?**

what you are asking,
*assigning*

**google : wiki**

and also assigning

**google : {**

**subval : 'yahoo'**

**}**

From both the above , You should **either allocate google to wiki** or google to **subobject**
Your requirement asks to do Both which contradicts the basic logic and hence not possible.